# Accessing Redux store from Method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently building a React application which uses the Redux store. I would like to test a particular method called `getFacilityName`, so I have began refactoring my code.

I need helping accessing the Redux Store inside of my getFacility method.

Method:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setCMSId } from '../redux/methods.js'

export default (props) => {

  props.dispatch(setCMSId("Hello"));
  console.log("[" + props.getState().cmsNum + "]");

  return "x";

};
```

I'm calling this method inside of the component `CMSForm`, which is inside the `App.js` container. My `index.js` is where I have created the Redux store.

It looks like I'm not using props correctly. I would like to access & change what's inside the Redux store within my getFacilityName method.

Please let me know if I need to explain more -

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't connected this component to the `redux` store. You've imported `{ connect }`, you just need to use it. By wrapping your component with the `connect` HOC, the `dispatch` method will be injected into the component. Something like this should work:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setCMSId } from '../redux/methods.js'

export default connect(state => ({ 
   cmsNum: state.cmsNum  // mapping state to component props
}), {
 setCMSId // automatically dispatched when called thanks to `connect`
})(({ cmsNum, setCMSId, ...props }) => {

  setCMSId("Hello");
  console.log("[" + cmsNum + "]");

  return "x";

});
```